# Очистка бакета Google Cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud, storage, gsutil

Существует необходимость очищать папки с датами формата:

```
gs://project1/project_ios/stage/blablalba/201906131348/
```

За каждые 60 дней. Возможно ли сделать это средствами gsutil. Пока остановился на такой команде:

```
gsutil ls -l gs://project1/project_ios/stage/blablalba/201906131348/ | sort -k2n | head -5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать ['object lifecycle'](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/managing-lifecycles#enable) для целого бакета. Поставить правило, что объекты старше 60 дней в бакете автоматически удалялись. Вам нужно создать json [файл конфигурации](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/managing-lifecycles#configexamples) и используя gsutil назначить данный lifecycle для бакета:

> gsutil lifecycle set [LIFECYCLE_CONFIG_FILE] gs://[BUCKET_NAME]